# Internet Slow when No HDMI

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, internet

I am not sure this issue to be post or not here. But I feel something strange in raspberry.

Let me explain.

My Raspberry Pi 4 Board is connected with Ethernet cable and I have installed remote application to access my Raspberry Pi with `teamviewer`. I'm feeling in Raspberry Pi Internet slow or slow access while using `TeamViewer` from my PC. My PC also connected with same network, so same source internet is available for Raspberry Pi and PC.

When HDMI Is connected with Raspberry Pi 4, and I'm accessing Raspberry Pi via `TeamViewer` from my PC, Internet looks fine, able to access and open something via `TeamViewer`. But when I removed HDMI and do the same thing, Accessing speed become slow via TeamViewer.

### OS and/or distribution

```
$uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.84-v7l+ #1613 SMP Thu Jan 5 12:01:26 GMT 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here, but it could be that the GPU and/or GPU clocks go down when you remove the HDMI cable.

You can check the frequencies of CPU and GPU by running:

CPU:

```
vcgencmd measure_clock arm
watch -n1 vcgencmd measure_clock arm
```

GPU:

```
vcgencmd measure_clock v3d
```